# Burning the image generated by building the freeRTOS onto raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, freertos

I have build it using this git-hub repo https://github.com/jameswalmsley/RaspberryPi-FreeRTOS
Then pasted the kernel.img generated by building the freeRTOSto the sd card which earlier contained raspbian, replacing its existing kernel.img file.
But this doesn't seem to work. I connected my raspberry pi to a monitor and it displays a colored screen.

Is there any fix for this?? Please help

Comment: FreeRTOS is a small kernel for microchip, raspberry is a device to run full linux distribution, which are different device for different purpose. I doubt FreeRTOS has any video capabilities or bufferframe for display or any of the driver you need for the raspberry board or chip components.

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting a .img file will not boot the OS.

You will first need to create an MBR (master boot record) on your SD card using a tool like RUFUS https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Then, you will need to use the win32 disk imager tool to write the file to your SD card. https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download

Then you can boot the SD card.

DISCLAIMER::
Whilst I have done my best to ensure that the links provided are for the programs I have described, please understand that I am not responsible for the content hosted on these sites. By extension, I am not liable to any damage caused by the sites or programs themselves.